# cakephp 2.6 confirm message spanish chars fails due to json_encode

Tags: json, cakephp, confirm

my view code:

```
$confirm='¿Está seguro de que quiere borrar el nº 1?';
$this->Html->link(__d('phkapa', 'Send'), array('action' => 'send', $ticket['Ticket']['id']),array('escape' => true, 'confirm'=> $confirm));
```

result in alert box is :
\u00bfEst\u00e1 seguro de que quiere borrar el n\u00ba 1?

cakephp 2.6 and all app is on utf8 ...

is this a bug on cake 2.6 or am i missing something? or any ideas how to resolve this without changing the core function that returns a string to be used as onclick handler for confirm dialogs.
this function uses json_encode like $message = json_encode($message) and this is the problem, the json_enconde outputs \u00bf instead of ¿

unfortunaly we cant use option JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE, that encodes multibyte Unicode characters literally (default is to escape as \uXXXX), since is only available since PHP 5.4.0.

Comment: The browser should be able to handle escaped unicode sequences just fine and display the chars properly (Fx, Chrome, IE, Opera, Android Browser, etc, they all do fine for me). Which browser/version are you using, and what exactly does the generated source look like?

Comment: <a href="/phkapa/phkapa/review/send/1" onclickeval="if (confirm(&quot;\u00bfEst\u00e1 seguro de que quiere borrar el n\u00ba 1?&quot;)) { return true; } return false;">Enviar</a>

Comment: Chrome Version 40.0.2214.115 (64-bit)      Firefox 36   both on ubuntu 14 , <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: `onclickeval` ? Also does this happen in all browsers? Have you tested just the code snippet in a plain HTML document to check if it happens there too?

Comment: the problem is  cake 2.6 and the core  function that returns a string to be used as onclick handler for confirm dialogs $message = json_encode($message) , the correct awnser could be use JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE as json_encode option , but this is only available since PHP 5.4 and we are working with 5.3

Comment: That's not a general problem, as I said, browsers can handle this just fine, it's a local problem specific to your end. **http://jsfiddle.net/chzad5aw/** | **http://i.imgur.com/N5jBpuU.png**

Comment: you are correct , this fiddle test also works fine on my browsers ...

Comment: Then you should check where the difference is, maybe your app sends the wrong encoding (not sure if this would trip the browser tough), maybe there is something else on the page that causes that behavior (again, what is `onclickeval`?) ...

Comment: found it , onclickeval is the root of the problem ;)  ..  im using a jquery plugin catching onclick events and changing the attribute onclick to onclickeval. Thank's for your help and time ..

Comment: You're welcome. You may want to add that as an answer and accept it later on so that the question appears resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding the value with PHP first via `urlencode`.  Hopefully CakePHP decodes the values when it produces the HTML output.

```
$confirm = urlencode ( '¿Está seguro de que quiere borrar el nº 1?' );
$this->Html->link(__d('phkapa', 'Send'), array('action' => 'send', $ticket['Ticket']['id']),array('escape' => true, 'confirm'=> $confirm));
```

You can also see this JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/daeyebpu/ that demonstrates encoding/decoding.

Saludos desde Colorado